# How to send non-alternative multiple parts using system.net.mail

Tags: c#, mime, multipart, system.net.mail, mailmessage

I have emails with multipart/mixed body which contains nested multipart/related parts with Html part and related image part. Is there any way to construct these emails as MailMessage instances of System.Net.Mail?

This is not an alternateview question.

1. multipart/mixed
   1.1.    multipart/related
   1.1.1.        text/html
   1.1.2.        image/gif
   1.2.    multipart/related
   1.2.1.        text/html
   1.2.2.        image/gif

1.1.1 is related with 1.1.2. But it is not related with 1.2.2.
1.1.1 and 1.2.1 are separate html bodies.

I have pasted a sample message below.

```
Message-ID: <mhtml-11@dsv.su.se>
Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2000 04:18:00 +0200
From: MHTML <mhtml@dsv.su.se>
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: mhtml@dsv.su.se
Subject: Test message no. 11
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==boundary-2"

--==boundary-2
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="==boundary-1"; type="text/html"
Content-Location: http://www.dsv.su.se/jpalme/mimetest/

Text displayed only to non-MIME-compliant mailers
--==boundary-1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Test message no. 11 first part</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>This is test message no. 11 first HTML part</H1>

<H2>Here comes the red test image:</H2>
<IMG SRC="http://www.dsv.su.se/jpalme/mimetest/red-test-image.gif" 
BORDER=0 HEIGHT=32 WIDTH=117 ALT="red test image">

<P>This is the last line of this test message.
</BODY></HTML>

--==boundary-1
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-ID: <image1.mhtml-11@dsv.su.se>
Content-Location: http://www.dsv.su.se/jpalme/mimetest/red-test-image.gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="red-test-image.gif"
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==
--==boundary-1--
--==boundary-2
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="==boundary-1"; type="text/html"
Content-Location: http://www.dsv.su.se/jpalme/mimetest/

Text displayed only to non-MIME-compliant mailers
--==boundary-1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Test message no. 11 second part</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>This is test message no. 11 second HTML part</H1>

<H2>Here comes the yellow test image:</H2>
<IMG SRC="cid:image2.mhtml-11@dsv.su.se" BORDER=0 HEIGHT=32 WIDTH=152
ALT="yellow test image">

<P>This is the last line of this test message.
</BODY></HTML>

--==boundary-1
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-ID: <image2.mhtml-11@dsv.su.se>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="yellow-test-image.gif"
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--==boundary-1--
--==boundary-2--
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some free library, check MailMessagesExamples.zip:
http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Examples/

Or google some other library.

Mime is pretty complex, to compose valid messages from string is hard, is some unicode chars inside.

Comment: I am aware of lumisoft's library. I have looked at other open source stuff like MimeKit. Due to my requirements, I had to develop my own parser. If I can solve this issue above, that will be perfect.

Comment: I can't see that MailMessage will allow to Parse or construct complex messages, so you can't do it. Why you need so desperately MailMessage ? Why you don't do your own class then ? If you need SmtpClient class, then it's a problem, but you can code your own SMTP client the, if using some free availble library is not a option.